# Hibernate createSQLQuery with Transformers.aliasToBean and addScalar

Tags: hibernate

Not sure what's the best way for doing this since I am not VERY familiar with Hibernate.
Let's say I have an entity EmployeeDAO with field monthly_salary, and I want to know annual salary of the employee so I create an alias field annual_salary. To handle this alias fields I create a class Employee to extend EmployeeDAO. If I do as following I can only load the alias fields (I hope I don't have to addScalar for each column fields), what's the best way to load column fields and alias fields at the same time? Please note my original sql is more complicated, I have to use createSQLQuery function, following is just an example.

```
String sql = "Select e.*, e.monthly_salary*12 as annual_salary from Employee e";
List<Employee> fChk = session.createSQLQuery(sql).create
                    .addScalar("annual_salary", new BigDecimalType())
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
                    .list();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Ok, lucky me figure out how to solve it. Create a new Class Employee, inside it has the alias fields and EmployeeDAO obj. Problem solved

String sql = "Select e.*, e.monthly_salary*12 as annual_salary from Employee e";
List<Employee> emp = session.createSQLQuery(sql)
.addEntity("e", EmployeeDAO.class)
.addScalar("annual_salary", new BigDecimalType())
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Employee.class))
.list();

---------
public class Employee{
   private EmployeeDAO e;
   private BigDecimal annual_salary;
   ...setter and getter
}
```